# How do I use regex to return 2 separate pieces of {{...}} chunks in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
string = "{{1:123}} asdfadfasdfdfdfsaf {{1212:}}"
```

This is my current regex pattern:

```
var pattern = /[{{].*[}}]/;
```

When use match, I get:

```
string.match(pattern)
//returns ["{{1:123}} asdfadfasdfdfdfsaf {{1212:}}"]
```

How do I get just the first bracket chunk, or better yet, get an array that has each bracket chunk? My ideal return result would be:

```
["{{1:123}}", "{{1212:}}"]
```

Comment: `.*` is greedy, and will gobble up as much of the string as possible. try `.*?` to make it non-greedy. and note that `[{{]` ispointless. that's a character class. it matches a single character, not two. it's literally "if any single one of the characters inside the `[]` are present at this point in the string"

Comment: awesome, I adjusted it to /[{][{].*?[}][}]/g;

Comment: but why isn't it /[{][{].?[}][}]/g; ? why do you still need the asterisk?

Comment: `[{]` is again pointless. a single-char char class is just cargo-cult programming. `[]` is used for specifying mutiple characters, e.g. `[A17bQ#]` or ranges of characters `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: No need to use `[}]` and `[{]`. The braces are no special regex characters in this case, no escaping is necessary.

Comment: @jlei You need the asterisk to match multiple characters. `?` by itself just means the preceding character is optional. When put after `*` or `+` it means that the quantifier should be non-greedy.

Comment: @jlei: no. `.` = "single character". `?` = "zero or one of the previous", `*` = "zero or more of the previous". `.?` matches zero or one characters. `.*` matches zero-or-more.

Comment: And `*?` means *match 0 or more, but as few as possible*, and `+?` means *match 1 or more, but as few as possible*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove square brackets and use a lazy quantifier:

```
var pattern = /{{.*?}}/g;
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dY8aL5/1)

The `[{{]` matches just one `{` as it is a character class. Same with `[}}]`, it matches 1 `}`. See more about [**character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

The `.*` matches as many any chars other than a newline as possible, you get a substring from the first `{{` up to the last `}}` if you use it. Lazy quantifier will match up to the first `}}`. Also, see [**What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) and especially [**Lazy Quantifier Solution**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution).

```js
var re = /{{.*?}}/g; 
var str = '{{1:123}} asdfadfasdfdfdfsaf {{1212:}}';
console.log(str.match(re));
```

Comment: If you have very long substrings inside `{{` and `}}`, you might want to unroll the lazy dot as `var pattern = /{{[^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*}}/g;`

Comment: Also, see [*What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)